# Moving case sensitive Linux files via Windows

Tags: filesystems, magento, case-insensitive

the company I work for is currently trying to move a Magento installation from one server to another - however, the product images are saved in folders alphabetically indexed folders - but with an added twist, some of the letters are the same but have a different case -

i.e.

a, A, b, C, D, e, E, f, F, G, h, I

That being the case, when we try to drag those files down from FTP in order to move them, Windows does not honour the case sensitive distinction and we are losing several image folders. Is there a simple workaround for this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

regards
SWK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a Linux -> Windows -> Linux move?

If so, then just tar/gzip the directory, FTP it across and unpack.

command to create an archive:

```
tar czf archive.tar.gz /path/to/current/install
```

command to unpack:

```
cd /new/path
tar zxf archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: many thanks, that should do the trick - though in hindsight I feel slightly thick! Linux not my native environment...

Comment: no prob, that's what this site is for :)